# Regex to extract last item after TAB in line?

Tags: regex

Using the Perl regex engine, I can't figure out how to extract the last item in a line where items are split using the TAB character.

Here's an example from the Process Explorer log file:

```
^advapi32.dll\tAdvanced Windows 32 Base API\tMicrosoft Corporation\t5.1.2600.5755\tC:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll$
```

I tried the following, to no avail:

- \t\w$: "Search string '\t\w$' not found!". Makes sense, as "\" isn't
  taken into account
- \t[^\t].+?$: Starts from the second column
- [^\t].+?$: Whole line

Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use greediness of the wildcards: they will eat up as much as the can. For example if you want to match a whole line, use: `^.*\t([^\t]+)$`. The `^.*\t` matches everything that precedes a `tab` (including it) and the `([^t]+)$` group matches what you are looking for (and you can reference it with `$1` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You were not far : very simply `\t[^\t]+$` (or  `\t([^\t]+)$` if you can capture group from the result (the group you're looking for is inside the parenthesis)

Comment: Thanks but I tried "\t([^\t]+)$" and it simply removes the last\t before the last item

Comment: Can you explain further what you're doing with these regexp, exactly ? Because I can assure you that this one matches what you need.

Comment: Ok, forget it. I just saw you gave credit to another one...